# Teamcity doesn't detect msbuild nor nUnit failures when executed from powershell

Tags: msbuild, nunit, teamcity, psake

I have written a build script using psake which I run in Teamcity.

I have Teamcity 6.0, so I run psake from a .cmd, but I don't think that changes anything.

Everything is working fine, but I have two problems.

1. Nunit isn't communicating with Teamcity so when a test fails, Teamcity says everything is ok.
2. MsBuild behaves the same. Even though the build fails, Teamcity reports success.

I would like to know how get Teamcity to detect these failures.

Here is my example script: https://github.com/MikeEast/BuildTests/blob/master/build/build.ps1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably need to notify Teamcity yourself via its simple but elegant **[build status notification system](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity)**.

For example, you could output the following message to stdout during your powershell script.

```
##teamcity[buildStatus status='FAILURE' text='Some error message']
```

Comment: And, lucky for you, TeamCity just [published a lib](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/TeamCity.ServiceMessages) for creating those messages!

Comment: It works, but I was hoping for some magic stuff. Like mspec.exe has a `--teamcity` switch that produces this. I had hoped that the TeamCity Nunit testrunner had the same thing somehow.

Answer (score 2):

The way I have got TeamCity working (with TeamCity version 6.5.4 I must add) is to use the TeamCity module that is provided in the psake download.

Add this to your script:

```
...
Import-Module "$build_dir\psake\teamcity.psm1"

#Tasks here
...
Remove-Module teamcity

#End Of File
```

I have a build folder that I have put the module in so that all my builds can access it.

Then it worked out of the box.

I am not using the built in NUnit runner though, I have also put the NUNit console in my build folder and then call that with each UnitTest assembly:

```
Task Test -depends Build {
    $testAssemblies = (get-childitem $base_dir -r -i "*UnitTests.dll" -exclude "*.config" -Name | Select-string "bin")
    foreach($test_asm_name in $testAssemblies) {
        $full_test_assembly_name = "$base_dir\$test_asm_name"
        Exec { invoke-expression "$nunitconsole_path $full_test_assembly_name" }
    }
}
```

Comment: We are executing xunit like this: exec { & "$lib_dir\xunit\xunit.console.clr4.exe" "$($p.BuildDir)\$($p.Name).dll" /nunit "$($p.BuildDir)\results.xml"; } and it works great. However, the build always succeeds, when it should fail when there is a test issue.